# Cannot convert an array value in an array value

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pipeline

I have scraped my website using scrapy and passed it down to pipelines.py file for further processing and stored my data in an object as follows:

```
newsInfo = {
    "title" : newsArray['title'],
    "author": newsArray['author'],
    "content": contentString,
    "image": newsArray['image'],
    "time": newsArray['time'],
    "date": newsArray['date'],
    "category": newsArray['category'],
    "source": newsArray['source'],
    "summary": summarizedContent
}
```

where `newsArray = ItemAdapter(item).asdict()`

Now, for saving it in my firestore, I have done the following:

```
tech_ref = db.collection(u'Old12').document(u'Tech1').collection(u'News')
tech_ref.add(newsInfo)
```

But on running the scrapy, I get the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Cannot convert an array value in an array value.
```

The sample data in spiders.py is as follows:

```
{
    'title': 'Elon Musk tells Tesla staff to return to office or leave'
    'author': 'Reuters'
    'content': 'Two Tesla sources confirmed the authenticity of the email reviewed by Reuters. Tesla did not respond to a request for comment.'
    'image': 'https://i.dawn.com/primary/2022/06/6297829b03172.jpg'
    'time': 'a day ago'
    'date': 'June 1, 2022'
    'category': 'Tech'
    'source': 'DAWN'
}
```

And summary is a variable that comes from a function (this works fine and is getting saved in firebase alone)

But, when I have tried to print the scraped data from pipelines.py file, some round brackets are being attached to it as follows:

```
{
    'title': ('Elon Musk tells Tesla staff to return to office or leave')
    'author': ('Reuters')
    'content': ('Two Tesla sources confirmed the authenticity of the email reviewed by Reuters. Tesla did not respond to a request for comment.')
    'image': ('https://i.dawn.com/primary/2022/06/6297829b03172.jpg')
    'time': ('a day ago')
    'date': ('June 1, 2022')
    'category': ('Tech')
    'source': ('DAWN')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried saving to Firebase using [mock data](https://feliperego.github.io/blog/2019/01/11/Creating-Fake-Mock-Data-Python) to see if the error persists?

Could you post a sample of the data you are trying to save to Firebase from scrapy?

Comment: Yes, I have tried saving mock data to firebase and there is no problem in that. I haved updated the question with sample data

Comment: It is strange that adds those parentheses. Have you taken a look at this [Python Scrapy tutorial](https://letslearnabout.net/tutorial/scrapy-tutorial/python-scrapy-tutorial-for-beginners-01-creating-your-first-spider/)?